# What is the meaning of error when knitting a r notebook

Tags: r

I am trying to knit an R notebook and found that it suddenly generate a strange error.

What I am trying to do is as follow:

1. Create a new R notebook on R studio desktop
2. Change the first line to "Two data set was provided "
3. try to knit it

I am getting this error:

```
source("test.Rmd")
Error in source("test.Rmd") : 
  test.Rmd:6:5: unexpected symbol
5: 
6: Two data
       ^
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: You are sourcing the file not knitting it.  R is trying to interpret `Two data..` as R commands.  Use `knitr::knit("test.Rmd")` instead

Comment: I am clicking on the knite button on R studio, I am not using the command line!

Comment: I don't know what would cause that.  Can you knit other Rmd files?  What happens if you restart RStudio or reload the file?

Comment: It is doing this. I noted that it actually can knite to the word, but the preview doesn't work. I solved the problem by knitting to the word and checking the output there.